# JS Object, how to access objects from within myself

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop

So, i see no reason why this isn't working but i am at a wall and frustrated. Why can't i call this.myself from within the wyr.message.close function? Maybe my understanding of this is scewed but i was sure this is referring to the object itself, not the function.

```
this.myself is undefined
```

Code:

```
wyr.message = {
    myself: $('.message'),
    init: function() {
        if(this.myself.is(':visible')){
            setTimeout(this.close, 5000);
        }
    },
    close: function(){
        this.myself.fadeOut(1200,function(){
            this.myself.remove();
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you add a usage example? It's not totally clear what you want to do with `message` and there may be a more idiomatic way to accomplish your goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
wyr.message = {
    myself: $('.message'),
    init: function() {
        var self = this;
        if(this.myself.is(':visible')){
            setTimeout(function(){
                self.close();
            }, 5000);
        }
    },
    close: function(){
        this.myself.fadeOut(1200,function(){
            $(this).remove();
        });
    }
}
```

The issue is context. Within the callback function passed to `fadeOut`, `this` is bound to the element being worked on by jQuery, not to the `wyr.message` object.

**EDIT**:

There's also an issue with the `init` method. `SetTimeout` will bind the value of `this` to the global (`window`) object - so we save a reference to the `this` we want and use that to invoke the `close` method.

You could also look into `Function.prototype.bind`, but it's not supported in older browsers.

Comment: humm this said. I now get the same error on the this.myself.fadeOut. Not quite sure how that works out. it is undefined.

Comment: Oh, right. My bad. Didn't even look at the `init` method... There's a context issue there, too. I've edited my answer.

Comment: its to late to look :o bed time. But i'm sure i fixed this issue, i'll have a proper look soon. Crazy busy with interviews at the mo. But thanks for checking back

Answer (score 0):

First, javascript object literal property expressions are evaluated at the time you create the object instance. `myself` will be whatever that selector grabs at that time, which is probably nothing. The `myself` property needs to be a function if you want it to return the value of `$('.message')` at the time of invocation. As a consequence you'll need to change all uses to function calls as well.

Second, during the execution of the setTimeout callback, `this` is bound to the window object, so you need to qualify it appropriately:

```
  wyr.message = {
    myself: function() { return $('.message'); },
    init: function() {
      if(this.myself().is(':visible')){
        setTimeout(this.close, 5000);
      }
    },
    close: function(){
      message.myself().fadeOut(1200,function(){
        $(this).remove();
      });
    }
  };
```

(Note, this will fade out and remove everything matching the selector when the timeout fires.)